# how to use gitub actions setup-node

Tags: node.js, github, github-actions

I have a runner with nodejs version 14.20.0 installed. I would like to use the github provided [actions/setup-node](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) using node version 18.18.2 and tried this on my yaml file

```
  - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
    with:
      node-version: '18.18.2'

  - name: Perform npm
    working-directory: ${{ github.workspace }}/my-app
    run: |
      node --version
      npm i
```

It was completed without issues however when I check the logs the runner still uses the version 14.20.0 based from the logs (see logs below). Please help me on what I missed here.

```
Run actions/setup-node@v4
  with:
    node-version: 18.18.2
    always-auth: false
    check-latest: false
    token: ***
  env:
    ENV: test
Attempting to download 18.18.2...
Acquiring 18.18.2 - x64 from https://github.com/actions/node-versions/releases/download/18.18.2-6796085386/node-18.18.2-linux-x64.tar.gz
Extracting ...
/usr/bin/tar xz --strip 1 --warning=no-unknown-keyword --overwrite -C /runner/_work/_temp/xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx -f /runner/_work/_temp/xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx
Adding to the cache ...
Environment details
  node: v18.18.2
  npm: 9.8.1
  yarn:



Perform npm
Run node --version
  node --version
  npm i
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -ileo pipefail {0}
  env:
    ENV: test
bash: cannot set terminal process group (13): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
v14.20.0
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@3. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN my-app-functions@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN my-app-functions@1.0.0 No repository field.

added 193 packages from 136 contributors and audited 193 packages in 26.389s

22 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 moderate severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```